# Where is the data about certificate is stored when i run dspublish in a domain joined computer?

Tags: ldap, pki, certutil

When is run the command `certutil -f -dspublish "CA01_Fabrikam Root CA.crt" RootCA`

Output is

`ldap:///CN=Fabrikam Root CA,CN=Certification Authorities,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=fabrikam,DC=com?cACertificate`

Certificate added to DS store.

`ldap:///CN=Fabrikam Root CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=fabrikam,DC=com?cACertificate`

Certificate added to DS store.

`CertUtil: -dsPublish command completed successfully.`

Where is this certificate information actually stored? Where is the DS store?

Comment: The output that you've included is literally the address of where it's stored.

Comment: @user1686 apart from ad browser is there any way to see where in the filesystem it is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CA information is literally stored in the printed Active Directory object:

```
CN=Fabrikam Root CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

The certificate itself is stored in binary form in the `cACertificate` attribute of the AD object.

The file is not stored on the file system, but within the Active Directory database, which is located in the `C:\Windows\NTDS` folder by default.